# Text to xml generation with LLM dataset creation

Tags: large-language-model, huggingface, xml-generation

I'm a newbie in LLM, what I want to achieve is to train LLM in the way that It generates from text description to XML of some blocks,

There are some blocks with input and output ports with some connections in between, i want it to describe it in XML

How can do that? any hint?
Thanks in advance

Comment: you should have a dataset for fine-tuning. 
here an interesting article about finetuning https://www.e2enetworks.com/blog/how-to-leverage-mistral-7b-llm-as-a-coding-assistant